# Why is TYPE_ADDED_TO_INTERFACE considered a breaking change?

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I am using the Apollo Server implementation of GraphQL, together with the Apollo Engine, and specifically the functionality to check whether a schema diff contains any breaking changes. I'd like to understand better why `TYPE_ADDED_TO_INTERFACE` is considered to be a breaking change, and if anyone can provide an example of a graphql query that would break, as a consequence?

I'm using the `apollo/2.9.0 darwin-x64 node-v10.10.0` to perform the schema check with the `apollo service:check` command.

For example, if I have this schema:

```
interface Animal {
  id: ID
}

type Dog implements Animal {
  id: ID
  favoriteToy: String
}
```

And then add this to the schema:

```
type Cat implements Animal {
  id: ID
}
```

This is considered a breaking change. Why?

I can see that if someone is making a query for all the `Animal` objects, and has a `... on Dog` fragment in the query, they would start getting `Cat` objects back with only the interface fields, until they also add a `... on Cat` fragment. Is that what's considered breaking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a type implement an interface it previously did not should not break existing queries. To your point, even if the inline fragment is omitted, the results will still be valid (they could result in an empty object being returned if no interface fields were selected, but that's still a valid response).

I could, however, foresee issues in specific clients resulting from this kind of change. For example, when using Apollo client, we often create an [IntrospectionFragmentMatcher](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/fragments/#fragments-on-unions-and-interfaces) to specifically help the client correctly cache results from union or interface fields.

> To support result validation and accurate fragment matching on unions and interfaces, a special fragment matcher called the IntrospectionFragmentMatcher can be used. If there are any changes related to union or interface types in your schema, you will have to update the fragment matcher accordingly.

In other words, having the schema change in this way could break client caching behavior. I suspect for clients that do schema-based code-generation, like `apollo-android`, this could also result in some runtime weirdness.